# How can i delete a file from my ftp server when selecting the file in a treeView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp, treeview

In my treeView1 i display the structure of my ftp server.
Right click on a file i have options menu and i select Delete.

```
private void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Delete")
            {
                delete(treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
            }
        }
```

And

```
public void delete(string deleteFile)
        {
            try
            {                      
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
                FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;
                Uri serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + txtHost.Text);
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri + "/" + deleteFile);
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }
```

The problem is for example the file in the variable deleteFile is: root\B\a-new-beginning.jpg
Since i'm getting it from the treeView1

But to delete a file from the ftp server the format of the path should be:

root/B/a-new-beginning.jpg

So serverUri + "/" + deleteFile should be: ftp://ftp.test.com/root/B/a-new-beginning.jpg
And now serverUri is wrong it's:  ftp://ftp.test.com/root\B\a-new-beginning.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple replace

```
string url = @"ftp://ftp.test.com/root\B\a-new-beginning.jpg";
url = url.Replace('\', '/');

// now, backslashes are replaced with slashes
// ftp://ftp.test.com/root/B/a-new-beginning.jpg

Uri serverUri = new Uri(url);
```